# Passing a concept-constrained function overload

Tags: c++, overloading, c++20, c++-concepts, overload-resolution

The following code fails to compile ([Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/Gd89b7nTq)):

```
#include <concepts>

template <class Fn>
decltype(auto) g(Fn&& fn) { return fn(); }

template <typename T>
requires(std::integral<T>) int f() { return 0; }

template <typename T>
int f() { return 1; }

int main() {
  f<int>();
  f<void>();
  g(f<int>); // error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'int (&)()'
             // from an rvalue of type '<unresolved overloaded function type>'
  g(f<void>);
}
```

It seems unexpected to me that the overload resolution succeeds when calling `f<int>()` (selecting the constrained version as a better match than the unconstrained version) but fails when passing `f<int>` as an argument.

Note that changing the unconstrained version to a disjoint constraint does make it compile ([Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/7K5zs7zP3)):

```
#include <concepts>

template <class Fn>
decltype(auto) g(Fn&& fn) { return fn(); }

template <typename T>
requires(std::integral<T>) int f() { return 0; }

template <typename T>
requires(!std::integral<T>) int f() { return 1; }

int main() {
  f<int>();
  f<void>();
  g(f<int>);
  g(f<void>);
}
```

So is the compiler behavior correct? And if so, is this an inconsistency in the standard, or is it intended to work this way?

Comment: I'm not sure if the compilers are correct or not, but another workaround could be to add a cast: `g(static_cast<int(*)()>(f<int>));` [example](https://godbolt.org/z/b44d9v8j9). I'm not sure why that seems to help though. Edit: Oups, it only worked in clang++, not g++.

Comment: @TedLyngmo That doesn't seem to work, the ambiguity is at the point of conversion and not related to parameter passing.  `int (*x)() = &f<int>;` fails with the same error (on g++, as OP's godbolt link uses).

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes, I noticed when I changed from clang++ to g++. Odd that clang++ accepts that cast when it doesn't accept plain `g(f<int>)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that neither GCC nor Clang has fully implemented the rules for forming pointers to constrained functions: [over.over]/5 definitely **considers** constraint ordering in choosing an overload.  There were some [late changes](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2019/p1972r0.html) to these, although they’re just as relevant to the disjoint-constraints case as to the unconstrained case.